# When I try to create a custom server_name it just stays at the default Nginx page

Tags: nginx, homebrew, nginx-config

I've just received a new MacBook Pro, but I'm having struggles getting Nginx to work with Homebrew. I'm coming from an Linux Ubuntu environment and the Nginx configuration files seem to be located on different places with Homebrew.

So my localhost is working fine and shows the default Nginx welcome page, but when I try to create a custom server_name like `street.local` with a custom `root` directory like `~/Projects/Private/stroet/public` it just stays at the default Nginx page. I am reloading Nginx after saving the files with `brew services reload nginx`.

My question in short:

- How can I setup my Nginx with Homebrew correctly?

I've read [this file](https://gist.github.com/jimothyGator/5436538), but It wasn't really helpful because If I do what it says there `brew doctor` will say that the symbolic links are incorrect.

Thank you guys for helping me in advance!

Comment: too broad - Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Rob I've made an edit to my question. Is it good now?

Comment: What is your exact question? "How can I setup my Nginx with Homebrew correctly?" + "So my localhost is working fine" = ??

Comment: You've edited nginx config files in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/`, right?